# Testing empty object in Jasmine fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

If I have a variable setting to `{}` the following match errors

```
// Somewhere in my angular controller
self = this;
self.myVar = {};


// In my test file
// This errors out. I console.log myVar to make sure that it is indeed {}
expect(myVar).toEqual({});

// Note if I define myVar = {} in the same test spec it works
it('test', function(){
   var myVar = {};
   expect(myCtrl.myVar).toEqual({});
   expect({}).toEqual({});
});
```

What is the reason for this and how would you by pass this behavior? According to Jasmine doc

```
it("should work for objects", function() {
  var foo = {
    a: 12,
    b: 34
  };
  var bar = {
    a: 12,
    b: 34
  };
  expect(foo).toEqual(bar);
```

It seems like toEqual should test for object content?

Comment: Please post your controller. Unless `myVar` is a global variable (which is bad) `expect(myVar).toEqual({});` won't work

Answer (score 16):

Try:
`expect(result).toMatchObject({})`

Comment: short and simple

Answer (score 1):

You could try with the length property associated with the Object Keys present in your object to be evaluated:

```
expect(Object.keys(res).length).toBe(0); // or not.toBeGreaterThan(0)
```

If you are evaluating a non empty object you may use:

```
expect((Object.keys(res)).length).toBeGreaterThan(0) // or not.toBe(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your variable is getting out of scope from app and in the test case it is getting executed as undefined var

Answer (score 0):

```js
var empty = jasmine.empty();
expect(empty.asymmetricMatch(myvar));
```

=> [Code](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/main/src/core/asymmetric_equality/Empty.js) / [Doc](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.7/matchers.html)

Answer (score 0):

there are two solutions:

Either use toMatchObject({})

or try using toBeEmpty() from jest-extended.

-first, install jest-extended:

```
npm install --save-dev jest-extended
```

then use it in your test like other matchers from jest:

```
expect(result).toBeEmpty()
```